how to attach debugger and debug dart-frog backend application
I was reviewing dart-frog , but could not find a way to attach debugger from either Android Studio or VS Code to dart-frog.
I simply wants to put few breakpoints and inspect values of variable received, execute code line by line etc similar to what is done with Java/Spring with gradle bootRun --debug-jvm
